# Can't get jqueryui icons to show up

Tags: jquery-ui

I've tried like 20 different things, but I can't get any jqueryui icons to show up.

Some examples of a few things I've tried

1) With this in the header

```
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This in html

```
<span class="ui-icon-search" style="width: 20px; height: 20px; z-index: 9999; display: inline-block"></span>
```

2) With this in header

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This in html

```
<span class="ui-icon-search" style="width: 20px; height: 20px; z-index: 9999; display: inline-block"></span>
```

3) Also have tried locally, and doesn't work

Have tried like 20 other things, but nothing works, even though it shows the right class in the developer console. **And everything else works fine**. No errors are thrown in html, on page, etc.

On this page, http://api.jqueryui.com/theming/icons/ , it makes it sound so easy to add them... just by adding a class, which I've tried adding multiple different icon classes, but none of them show an icon. I'm using the resizable widget too, so I tried adding the class of `ui-icon-carat-2-n-s` in multiple different places in the html, resizable jqueryui code, etc.

So I guess, even a simple fiddle showing a working icon would be great.

Comment: Link to a site showing the issue? Did you download the images? The dev console will show you what path the browser is looking in for the images, so this should be trivial to fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are missing one of the class to inherit from: `ui-icon`.

Code:

```
class="ui-icon ui-icon-search"
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/YN53x/